# Groovy/Grails: Filtering with `findAllBy ... InList` as case insensitive

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a query that searches a name from a `Person` domain in a given list and retrieves the results but it is case sensitive.

```
List<Person> persons = Person.findAllByNameInList(personsDto*.name)
```

What I want is to search for person name as **case insensitive**. How do I do that using either `findAll` or `createCriteria` or `sqlRestriction` or any other means?

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for you,

```
  List searchList = personsDto*.name // considering this as a list
    List<Person> persons = Person.withCriteria {
      or {
        searchList.each { name ->
          // iLike will search result for both Cases
          ilike('property', "%$name%")
        }
      }
  }
    //printing list dump
    Println persons.dump()
```

Comment: This solution works. But, it is not performant. It iterates over all items and compares the name. If you have a better solution, I will gladly accept. Thanks.

Comment: If you have to perform query for this either you can perform 'in' query using grails with criteria or same thing using the simple SQL query,  comparing list is itself not a good practice if your list contains huge data, almost same processing you will need to perform that at SQL level as in the iteration, it is not bad if you have limited list content.

Comment: " it is not performant. It iterates over all items and compares the name." - To be clear, it iterates over all the names in `personDto` but does not iterate over all of the `Person` instances in the database.  I think you probably already know that, but just clarifying.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thanks for clarifying. I am glad to receive your comment. I am a big fan. Do you have a better suggestion on how to do this or do you think the proposed solution is the best?

Comment: @jeffScottBrown thanks for your clarification, but no any finder method is found in grails for such combination, but this is possible through the SQL query, can we do the grails executeQuery to overcome this drawback.

Comment: @biniam_Ethiopia  you can perform executeQuery, to perform such query, I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353549/making-mysql-in-clause-case-sensitive